# How to restore remote desktop (RDP) disconnect confirmation window

Tags: remote-desktop

Today as I was closing my remote desktop session I accidently miss clicked and checked the box on the disconnect confirmation window to not show the window again.

Is there a way to restore this?  I have checked the settings in RDP but I don't see anything related to confirmation popups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This setting is stored in the registry.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-re-enable-rdp-confirmation-on-disconnect/e0396c48-12fe-4108-8961-7992c4433f25) (And, infuriatingly enough, nowhere in the official RDP client or even the saved `.RDP` session files.)

Open `regedit` and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`. The key `"ShowShutdownDialog"` will be set to DWORD(0) if the "don't display again" box has been checked. Set it back to 1 to restore the confirmation.